# Задать поле таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая таблица:

```
word TEXT, par1 INEGER, par2 INEGER, par3 INEGER
```

Нужно установить параметр par3 исходя из первого параметра(par1). Пример:

```
 word         par1  par2  par3
'someword'    100   0.25  3
'someword1'   200   0.50  2
'someword3'   400   0.25  1
```

То есть выходит что 3-й параметр это своеобразный рейтинг который будет базироваться на первом параметре. Запись с максимальным значением par1 будет соответствовать значение номер 1, ну и так дальше.
В таблице сейчас примерно ~17k записей, и вот нужно как то установить этот третий параметр.

Comment: а по какой формуле вычисляется par3?

Comment: надо отсортировать таблицу по убыванию par1 и заполнить поле последовательными номерами. я тока для mysql умею

Comment: @Crystal это ранг или рейтинг. Первое место отдается строкам с максимальным значениями `par1`и.т.д.. У меня вопросы к автору: таблица обновляемая? Есть ли возможно переделать схему таблицы?

Comment: По первому параметру. Припутсим у нас есть три записи в таблице, **par1** у них таков **10. 15. 14**, соответственно **par3** будет **3, 1, 2**. Максимальное значение par1 в таблице будет ровняться номеру 1, и так далее...

Comment: @Sanek Zhitnik, Да, таблица обновляемая. И да, есть возможность переделать схему.

Comment: Есть тогда мысль вынести `par1` и `par3` в отдельную таблицу (пусть будет `rang_table`) , а в исходной таблице (назовем ее `table`) оставить только `rang_table_id`. При добавлении новой строки в основную таблицу вам нужно будет искать значение `par1` в `rang_table`. Преимущество в том, что если вы добавите строку со значением 500 , Вам не нужно будет пересчитывать ранги для 17 к строк, а лишь для строк из `rang_table`

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Буду тестить.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, есть ли в Вашей таблице PRIMARY KEY, поэтому я добавил его самостоятельно. Запрос будет таким:

```
drop table if exists Table1; 
create table 
       Table1
(
       id integer primary key,
       word text,
       par1 integer,       
       par2 float,       
       par3 integer
);

insert into Table1 select 1, 'someword', 100, 0.25, null;
insert into Table1 select 2, 'someword1', 200, 0.50, null;
insert into Table1 select 3, 'someword3', 400, 0.25, null;
insert into Table1 select 4, 'someword4', 300, 0.25, null;

drop table if exists temp.TmpTable; 
create temp table 
       TmpTable
(
       id integer,
       word text,
       par1 integer,       
       par2 float,       
       par3 integer

);

insert into temp.TmpTable 
select 
       id,       
       word,       
       par1,       
       par2,       
       par3       
from
    Table1    
order by 
      par1 desc;      

update
      Table1      
set
   par3 = (select tmp.ROWID from temp.TmpTable tmp where tmp.id = Table1.id);

select
      *      
from
    Table1    
order by
      par3

RecNo id word      par1 par2 par3 
----- -- --------- ---- ---- ---- 
    1  3 someword3  400 0.25    1 
    2  4 someword4  300 0.25    2 
    3  2 someword1  200  0.5    3 
    4  1 someword   100 0.25    4
```